# How to onDismissible with StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to erase the Card on ListView. 
I could know to wrap with Dismissible and to use onDismissed().
But I do't have any idea next step what I use the key().

Here is the progressing codes.
I commented on this code what is the problem.

```dart
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: fireStoreInstance
            .collection(email)
            .doc(gameId)
            .collection('items')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              if (document.data() == null || snapshot.hasError) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'No Data!',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.data != null && !snapshot.hasError) {
                return Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Dismissible(
                    onDismissed: (direction) {

                    // TODO: Here is the question code.

                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Image.network(document.data()["imageURL"]),
                      title: Text(document.data()["itemTitle"]),
                      subtitle: Text(document.data()["itemPoint"] + "pt"),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

V/r,

Comment: If you need to delete the data from Firestore you'll need to delete the documents associated with your Card with the `delete()` method based on the document ID. Find all the relevant information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents). It is also important to remove the document from the snapshot list.

Comment: In order to delete the Card itself from the ListView I believe that you'll find this posts within the community to be useful [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918425/how-to-implement-a-swipe-to-delete-listview-to-remove-data-from-firestore) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709165/how-to-delete-a-listview-document-from-firestore-in-android-when-i-click-it).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and advice. I appreciate it and check your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a stream, you need to delete the card from Firestore like this:

```
onDismissed: (direction) {
    await Firestore.instance.runTransaction(
      (transaction) async {
        await transaction.delete(snapshot.data.documents.yourIterator.reference);
      },
    );
}
```

also `document.data()` should be `document.data`